# Getting a Bitmap Object of a screenshot in VC++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bitmap, screenshot

I'm trying to write a program that grabs a screen shot of the current active window and then does some basic computer vision with the result.  The current code I have is as follows:

```
RECT rc;
HWND hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();    //the window can't be min
if(hwnd == NULL) {
    cerr << "it can't find any 'note' window" << endl;
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

//create
HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
SelectObject(hdc, hbmp);

//Print to memory hdc
PrintWindow(hwnd, hdc, PW_CLIENTONLY);

//Get the bitmap
BITMAP bm;
GetObject (hbmp, sizeof(bm), &bm);

//release
DeleteDC(hdc);
DeleteObject(hbmp);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
```

After everything's said an done, bm.bmBits is NULL.  This is especially strange because all of bm's other fields are correct.  Obviously I can't do very much without bm.bmBits.  Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This code is mostly copied from the answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292757/how-to-get-screenshot-of-a-window-as-bitmap-object-in-c), but in that code handle to a bitmap was never transferred into a BITMAP struct, but instead was used to add the bitmap to the clipboard.  Since I want to process the screenshot immediately, I'd rather extract the data within the handle immediately and process it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bm.bmBits is NULL because you don't own the memory referenced by the bitmap.  You need to have the kernel copy them for you, using [`GetDIBits`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144879%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or the like.