# Full screen application screenshot in c++?

Tags: c++, fullscreen, screenshot

I wish to take screenshots of fullscreen applications in a c++ program (i.e games like call of duty). I have tried using GDI and directx both can get screenshots of the desktop. However they just return black images when running fullscreen applications. Has anybody else manage to   solve this problem and if so how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take screenshot of DirectX full-screen application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962142/take-screenshot-of-directx-full-screen-application)

Comment: Have you tried to use the WinApi? Here's an example:
[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291167/how-to-make-screen-screenshot-with-win32-in-c

Comment: Here is a good link, assuming you are using windows: [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292757/how-to-get-screenshot-of-a-window-as-bitmap-object-in-c

Comment: Have tried the WinAPI still no luck

Comment: Assuming a *nix system, something along the lines of `cat /dev/fb0 > file` should catch the raw screen data into a file. You'll probably have to convert it into something other than raw screen information, but I am sure there are tools you can pipe the data through to do that.