# what parameter of PrintWindow should be used?

Tags: visual-c++, screen-capture

for some reason, I need to capture the screen of one application automatically, and I find one good example from link 
[How to get screenshot of a window as bitmap object in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292757/how-to-get-screenshot-of-a-window-as-bitmap-object-in-c)

During my test, I found a strange thing (my test is based on Windows 10 with Visual C++ 2008):

- in application of Windows notepad, I have to use parameter WM_PRINTCLIENT, or the captured is all black

  ```
  PrintWindow(hwnd, hdc, WM_PRINTCLIENT);
  ```
- in application that I want to capture, I have to use PW_CLIENTONLY, or the captured is all black

  ```
  PrintWindow(hwnd, hdc, PW_CLIENTONLY);
  ```

So my question is that: what's the difference between them, and is there any rules? I tried to searching it in Internet but didn't find good hint.

Comment: You are not passing a correct value for the 3rd argument.  It must be 0 (entire window) or PW_CLIENTONLY (client area).  What happens next entirely depends on how much work the programmer did to implement WM_PRINT and WM_PRINTCLIENT.  Always be prepared to be disappointed.

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks a lot for your help. I tested parameter 0 works for both my target application and notepad.