# Bitmap from program child window returns as black

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, bitmap, hwnd

Current situation:
I have a program called "NoxPlayer" which is basically an android emulator.
I also have a c++ program which locates the window handle of said NoxPlayer and makes a bitmap of the current state of the window and saves it to the clipboard.

But here comes the problem.

---

This is how the program looks to me: 
[NoxPlayer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoOLg.png)

And this is what it saves in the clipboard: [Clipboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6XIt.png)

But this is what i want: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhfb0.png)

---

I could have simple cut the top part of the bitmap but what i wish to try and do is get the inner part of the window as seen here [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhfb0.png) without cutting the bitmap.

I first tried going down the window hierarchy and getting the bitmap of child windows but what i got was black bitmaps as seen here: [Black window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YtP3.png)

Window hierarchy as seen from Microsoft Spy++: [Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJMYw.png)

The ones i marked around with red color are the ones i tried to get a bitmap from, since ScreenBoardClassWindow and all its children fall into this  [Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egdso.png) when checking their position by highlighting them in Microsoft Spy++

---

This is the code i used to create a bitmap and save it to the clipboard:

```
  RECT rc;
  GetClientRect(NoxHandle, &rc);

  //create
  HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
  HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
  HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen,rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
  SelectObject(hdc, hbmp);

  //Print to memory hdc
  PrintWindow(NoxHandle, hdc, PW_CLIENTONLY);

  //copy to clipboard
  OpenClipboard(NULL);
  EmptyClipboard();
  SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hbmp);
  CloseClipboard();

  //release
  DeleteDC(hdc);
  DeleteObject(hbmp);
  ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
```

Code is taken from here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7292773/7346067)

---

Thanks in advance

---

*EDIT*
The window i use to currently get the bitmap from is the Program Parent window ["NoxPlayer"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GySW4.png). When using any of the children windows I get the black bitmap problem.

Comment: So are you able to use Spy++ and find the right window with red highlights around it? Is it the `Child_1` window?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani yes i am able to use Spy++ and find the right window. But there are multiple windows at the same position and when trying to get the bitmap from them i end up with a black bitmap. However if i use the Parent window of the application i am able to get what i want, but with the need of cutting the top off

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Just realised i might have been unclear about a few window sizes. While the parent window covers the entire program, the others do not. The window that covers what i want are "ScreenBoardClassWindow" and "QWidgetClassWindow" since they cover this: [link](https://imgur.com/KkGlmp5) But the children of "QWidgetClassWindow" cover this: [link](https://imgur.com/tlnA5eo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the right window, example, `QWidgetClassWindow` then use `GetWindowRect` to find the coordinates in relation to desktop window. Use `BitBlt` instead of `PrintWindow`.

With this example the target application must be visible on the screen. It should not be obstructed by other windows.

```
RECT rc;
HWND hwnd = h_QWidgetClassWindow;
GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);
int w = rc.right - rc.left;
int h = rc.bottom - rc.top;

Sleep(3000);
//create
HDC hdc = GetDC(0);
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, w, h);
HBITMAP oldbmp = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memdc, hbmp);

BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, w, h, hdc, rc.left, rc.top, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);

//copy to clipboard
OpenClipboard(NULL);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hbmp);
CloseClipboard();

//release
DeleteDC(memdc);
DeleteObject(hbmp);
ReleaseDC(0, hdc);
```

Also make sure your application is DPI aware, so that it gets the right coordinates.

Comment: It indeed works now for some reason. I'm now interested to know why using BitBlt actually gets the correct bitmap result when using it on a child window while using PrintWindow does not.
I now get [this](https://imgur.com/HGIKVTI) without any cutting done.

Comment: Applications made by Qt are not standard Win32 programs, Qt does it's own thing with custom controls. `BitBlt(memdc,...., hdc_desktop,...)` will copy whatever is painted on desktop, so it doesn't depend on how Qt is painting. But `BitBlt` may not work either if source DC is not desktop DC.

Comment: Since BitBlt copies whatever is painted on the desktop, something covering will also be shown on the bitmap. Could this be avoided?
Currently i just SetForegroundWindow() before making a bitmap.

Comment: The only alternative is `DwmUpdateThumbnailProperties` which will draw the source window on your own top-level window, then you have to `BitBlt` the desktop DC again. So the source window is again painted on screen. But that's a lot of work with no real benefit. `SetForegroundWindow` is fine. Use `GetWindowPlacement` to restore window positions if needed.